# Optaplanner - How to model a timeslot pattern scheduling problem if certain type of tasks require less resource when they're scheduled in same slot?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm developing a daily timeslot pattern scheduling problem with task precedence and daily shifts resource constaint.

- Each product has several batches and each batch consists of sequential tasks (like prepare\mix\process etc.) to be scheduled.
- Tasks consume shift units and there are daily shift limits for each type of tasks.
- If two prepare tasks of same product are schedued on the same day, they consume 1 units of shift together, while each of them still use 1 shift unit if they are scheduled apart.
- Succeeding tasks (like mix or process) of same products won't benefit from scheduling together on the same day. If one mix task use 1 shift unit, then two mix tasks scheduled on the same day would consume 2 shift unit in total.

This senario differs from project job scheduling problem, where task durations variation depend on machines, not other tasks.

I've implemented a simple model without changeable resource requirement and it works. I came up with a dummy idea: manually combine each two prepare tasks together and consider it as one task. But this would make the model less versatile and harder to write drool rules.

Any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a shadow variable "modifiedProcessTime" in planning entity and updated by a Custom VariableListener when two or more tasks from same product same type are scheduled on the same day. The first task remains its original processing time, while other task are set to be zero.